# how to print unordered list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one Question

- Write a Javascript code to store a list of strings/sort it and print it in an unordered list

could you please tell me how to print unordered list in javascript ?
I do like  this use **Math.random** function but it is not printing the value

```
var arr=['abc','pqr','mnc'];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  console.log(arr[Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)]) ; 

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3s4Lqr0o/1/
It is not printing the all values?

Comment: Does print mean to print it on a printer?  Or just show the results in the console?

Comment: on console .or alert

Comment: @Community - the question says to sort, not randomize.

Comment: Why are you using `Math.random()`?  Your instructions say to `sort`, not randomize.

Comment: I suspect your assignment has a different interpretation. "Unordered list" is the name of the `<ul>` HTML element (as opposed to "ordered list", `<ol>`). I would refer to the shuffled list as "shuffled", or "randomized", not "unordered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem here is that `Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)` will return a number between 1 to 3. Your array only has elements at index 0, 1, and 2. So `abc` won't be printed at all.

The second problem is, there is no guarantee that your calculation will return every single number 0, 1 and 2 exactly once. You could be getting `arr[1]` three times in a row, resulting in `pqr` being printed 3 times.

I initially voted to mark this question as a duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array). My thought was that you can simply shuffle the array, then print the shuffled array. However, since this question has been reopened, I will propose an alternate solution.

```
arr = ['abc','pqr','mnc'];

while (arr.length > 0) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    console.log(arr[index]);
    arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Randomly select one element in the array, print it and then remove it from the array. Repeat until there are no more elements.

Comment: Amadan does bring up a good point in the comments. I simply took the question at face value, but his points are worth considering.